# Embedded element (Flash) hogs mouse wheel scrolling when hidden and displayed again

Tags: jquery, flash, keyboard, focus, scribd

Hey everyone, I would appreciate some insights. I have researched the infamous 'Flash hogging keyboard focus' issue, but I believe our issue may involve a workaround that someone else has already come across. I've tried the various solutions I've found on stackoverflow and other sites, which I summarize below.

We have a web app, and a particular interface loads several divs that we are using as "tabs". When a user clicks one of the tabs, we hide the current div and un-hide the new one. Our main tab (which is loaded when the page loads) embeds a document from Scribd, which is loaded as a Flash movie. When a user clicks on the Flash movie, they scroll with the mouse/keyboard like normal, and when they click outside of the document control returns as expected.

When they navigate to another tab and then return to the original tab and click on the embedded Flash to navigate within it, the embedded Flash steals control of the mouse scroll and won't let it go. The user can click in this document and scroll with the arrow keys and then click out of the document and scroll the parent window with the arrow keys, but mouse scrolling is still bound to the embedded Flash movie. The only remedy is a hard page refresh.

What I've tried when the user clicks a new tab:
If old tab is 'home', remove embedded element from the DOM:

`saved_element = $('[name="flash_embed_object_name"]').remove();`

If the new tab is 'home', add element back into the DOM:

`$('#parent_div').append(saved_element);`

This doesn't work -- I can confirm that the element is removed from the DOM, but when it is returned to the DOM it hogs mouse scrolling when clicked just like before.
I also tried a similar solution, but instead of removing the element I called

`$('[name="flash_embed_object_name"]').blur();`  and  `$('#clicked_tab_div').focus();`

but this didn't help either. Does anyone have any other ideas? My next thought is that I somehow need to stop the Flash movie from playing, and then it will return focus to the page.

Any input is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain the solution? I have a table and embedded pdf being retrieved from jquery ajax call. The mouse focus is on the pdf and I am unable to scroll the table.

Comment: I believe the solution involved us leaving the embedded element there, but manipulating its position so that it was off the viewable screen. When the the containing element was hidden and shown again, it caused some issues. I believe your case is a little different, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution was not to hide the div that contains the embedded Flash -- when doing so, the embedded element would 'refresh' when shown again. We changed the position of the element to essentially hide it from view, but without hiding it.